# how a String Set can be retrieve in Android from SharedPreferences

Tags: android, xml, sharedpreferences, store, datastore

I have a problem to getting retrieve values from sharedPreferences that stored as a String Set.

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
                set.add("Price: " + String.valueOf(item.getItemPrice()));
                set.add("Quantity: " + String.valueOf(QuantityofItem));
                set.add("Total: " + String.valueOf(BillValue));
                set.add(customizeMsg);
                set.add("Image: " + item.getItemImage());
                editor.putStringSet(item.getItemName(), set);
```

my StringSet contains these 5 values and i want to retrieve that stored data and retrieve as a list view . any method how it can be perform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to retrieve that stored data and retrieve as a list view.

**#.** I guess you are trying to retrieve stored `Set` data as `ArrayList`. Use below code to retrieve `Set` as `ArrayList` :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

// Set
Set<String> set = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(KEY_ITEM_NAME, new HashSet<String>());

// List
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(set);
```

**#.**  If you have stored multiple `Set` in `SharedPreferences` then do the same for others. Get `Set` by using `KEY_ITEM_NAME` value as `item.getItemName()`.

**#.** If you want to show it on `ListView` then follow the steps described by `@CommonsWare`

Comment: #FAT thanks :) , my String Set has multiple string values , so i wanna display single set as a single list Item , i.e. item when added to cart , the string set contains values for item price quantity name etc.

Comment: I got your point. If you are storing single `Set` for single `Item` then you should also store the `Item` name and this `name` will be required to get the exact `set` for that item >> `sharedPreferences.getStringSet(KEY_ITEM_NAME, new HashSet<String>())`. 1. Create a simple model class with name, price, quantity etc. for your Item. 2. get data set from preference using item name. 3. crate Item class object and set data to object. 4. Add item object to list using list.add(object)

Comment: hi . m getting stuck again .... :/ sharedPreferences.getStringSet(KEY_ITEM_NAME, new HashSet<String>())
as i storing the set of String with key 'itemName' so how can i access the stored values by which i dont know user which item adds to cart.

Comment: want to retrieve single StringSet and set as single row item of list.

Comment: You have to store item names also. Use another SET to store the item names. Then first retrieve  this SET and get the `itemnames` and use this `itemnames` to retrieve the individual item SET from sharedPreferences.

Answer (score 2):

> i have a problem to getting retrieve values from sharedPrefrences that stored as a String Set.

Unless you `commit()` or `apply()` that `editor`, your data will not be saved.

> i want to retrieve that stored data

Call `getStringSet()` on the `SharedPreferences`, passing in whatever key you are using (here, `item.getItemName()`).

> retrieve as a list view

You are welcome to create an `ArrayList` out of the `Set<String>` elements, then wrap that in an `ArrayAdapter`, then put the `ArrayAdapter` into a `ListView`.

Comment: yup i successfully saved data by Commit() and APply() , but just confused for getting them into a list view

Comment: 'Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
                    set.add("Price: " + String.valueOf(item.getItemPrice()));
                    set.add("Quantity: " + String.valueOf(QuantityofItem));
                    set.add("Total: " + String.valueOf(BillValue));
                    set.add(customizeMsg);
                    set.add("Image: " + item.getItemImage());
                    editor.putStringSet(item.getItemName(), set);
                    editor.apply();
                    editor.commit();'

Comment: m using 'Key' as a itemName, "item.getItemName()"